# VB [(Function) handles ...] equivalent in Delphi

Tags: vb.net, delphi, equivalent, handles

Say we had something like

```
Private Sub ClickObject(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e as System.Eventargs) 
Handles Object1.click, Object2.click, Object3.click
```

Which takes the event after the 'Handles' and sends them to the function.

Is there an equivalent for this in Delphi, and how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can create an event handler and assign it to multiple controls.

```
procedure TForm1.ThreeControlsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender = Button1 then
    HandleButton1Click
  else if Sender = ComboBox1 then
    HandleComboBox1Click
  else if Sender = Edit1 then
    HandleEdit1Click;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.OnClick := ThreeControlClick;
  ComboBox1.OnClick := ThreeControlClick;
  Edit1.OnClick := ThreeControlClick;
end;
```

Comment: You can also use the `Tag` property to differentiate between the different controls. `case (Sender as TComponent).Tag of ...`

Comment: UPDATE: Got it to work. Did have to do a bit of research on it. For where you had Object.Onclick := Function. The function had to be "@Function" with the @.

Comment: @Hayden: What version of Delphi are you using? The @ shouldn't have been necessary with any recent version.

Comment: You shouldn't have needed that, Hayden. Is "Function" really a method belonging to an object? It should be. Standalone functions are not compatible with event handlers. Using the "@" operator can turn a typed pointer into an untyped pointer, and untyped pointers can be assigned to just about any other pointer-like type, even if they're not really compatible. Turn on the "typed @ operator" compiler option and see whether your code still works.

Comment: I am using Lazarus, I'm not what version it uses. The @ quickly fixed it. I'm not an expert on delphi so this was a quick fix for me. However I will look into Your solutions to try learn something new. Thank you =).

Answer (score 4):

Add a `TActionList` to your form. Add a `TAction` to it and handle its `OnExecute` event as you would the `OnClick` event of some other control. Assign the `Action` properties of the controls to refer to the action you added to the action list. (This also causes the controls to acquire their captions and enabled and visible properties from the associated action. It's meant to make it easier to have menus and toolbar buttons have uniform states when they represent the same command.)